# What are Leader VRF and Block VRF values on Pooltool?

Tags: stake-pool, ouroboros

During slot battles or height battles between stake pools, the [realtime chain tip](https://pooltool.io/realtime) on Pooltool displays (B) and (L) for the pool that has a lower "Block" and "Leader" VRF value, respectively. [Here](https://pooltool.io/realtime/7960162) is an example of one such instance (height battle).

My question is twofold:

1. What are Block and Leader VRF values?
2. How do they relate to the winners/losers of slot battles and/or height battles?

Answer (score 1):

My crude understanding is:

What is a VFR?

> "A Verifiable Random Function (VRF) [MRV99] is the public-key version
> of a keyed cryptographic hash.  Only the holder of the private VRF
> key can compute the hash, but anyone with corresponding public key
> can verify the correctness of the hash." [Ref 1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-irtf-cfrg-vrf-03)

1. What are Block and Leader VRF values?

> In the Leader Log, assigned blocks are chosen by their VRF values or score. The
> pools with the lowest VFR wins (Andrew Westberg described it as, who
> can do the lowest Limbo).

2. How do they relate to the winners/losers of slot battles and/or height battles?

> In the case of slot or height battles, the pool with the lowest VRF
> wins. It use to be the case that small pools had a slight advantage
> for slot/height battles. In the Vasil upgrade (Praos), that is no
> longer the case [Ref 2](https://github.com/input-output-hk/ouroboros-network/issues/4051)

The source of truth is the [Shelley Ledger Spec](https://hydra.iohk.io/build/20980576/download/1/ledger-spec.pdf).